# Used book stores in Malta

Tags: shopping, malta

I wanted to do some thrift book shopping during my stay in Malta – not in terms of price, but in terms of books being second-hand/used. What are the places to visit? Especially of interest are those that offer language-related publications.

I have only been able to research the English part of the Internet, but I believe there might be more up-to-date info in Italian or Maltese. So far the only Google result on topic is an question from tripadvisor from 14 years ago, which I fear may be outdated.

Comment: You'll find them here: [second hand book stores in Malta](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=second+hand+book+stores+in+malta).

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, but I fear I won't: most of the results are outdated (the one from tripadvisor is 14 years old), and English is not the only valid language to search for — I don't speak Maltese or Italian, two other dominant languages.

Comment: Sorry, I posted that LMGTFY link instead of voting to close as a shopping question.

Comment: @WeatherVane no worries, a common mistake. I still thank you for your input, even though there are dozens of similar questions on Travel.

Comment: There are a few similar ‘shopping’ question on TSE that didn’t get closed. I think this one might attract an answer if the OP edits it to clarify their specific problem eg include what research they’ve already done and the outcome, and what language(s) are of interest

Comment: Closed and re-opened as I believe this is a valid question for the site.

Comment: The Malti for bookshop seems to be ħanut tal-kotb and a search for that reveals at least one such store in Malta but whether they sell used books I cannot say. Similarly searching for libreria Malta throws up some possibilities. I use DuckDuckGo not Google so your mileage may vary.

Comment: @mdewey thanks – there is a whole lot of bookstores, but just one that might have used books. Such stores tend not to have popular websites, but are rather only known by the locals.